# Different Representation Matrices from same Generating Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, computational-algebra

Motivation:  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859725/sifting-algorithm-for-group-generated-by-a-set) post.

$K \subset S_n, \langle K \rangle =G \leq S_n$. We can create a *Representation Matrix* $M$ from $K$ that represnts $G$ (**Furst. Hopcroft, Luks**).

**Question:** Is $M$ unique for a fixed $K$ i.e. can we generat two different *Representation Matrices* from same $K$   ?

**Edit:** Each row $i$ of $M$ represents the complete right traversal set of $G_i$ in $G_{i-1} $ where $G_i$ is the pointwise stabilizer of $\{ 1,2...i\}$ and $G_0=G$.

Comment: I guess it depends on the process (and meaning) of *a matrix that represents* $G$. I am familiar with matrix representations of groups (wherein each element of the group is represented by a square matrix), but it sounds like this is something different entirely :-)